# Point Sub Domain to Different Private IP Address

Tags: web-server, web-hosting

I have a domain name www.example.com which points to website #1 on my home VPS #1 (192.168.1.2:80) ..

I want to get another domain name and also point it to my same Public IP address but access another VPS in my home network (192.168.1.3:80) ...

If its not possible then how do hosting companies do it? I doubt they have thousands of public IP addresses??!

Comment: They often don't use _private_ IP addresses.

Answer (score 3):

> If its not possible then how do hosting companies do it? I doubt they have thousands of public IP addresses??!

Of course they have thousands of public IP addresses, a single /16 has over 65,000 IP addresses in it.

But you can accomplish this by using a *reverse proxy* and pointing both sites to that and having it do the proxying to your internal servers if you don't want to buy a second public IP.

Answer (score 1):

The basics is to have a server in your home handling the redirection as @MDMarra explained.

For this you can use Apache2: on your publicly accessible address (192.168.1.2 in your private network) you configure one Apache2 server, with two ServerName. The first one will redirect to you current computer as usual, the second one will "proxy" requests to another Apache2 on the private server at 192.168.0.3.

If it's not enough, I could show you a bit of configuration to get started, but you won't be able to understand with just that. You need to read about: VirtualHost, ServerName, Proxying and general Apache2 configuration first.

As for how the hosting companies do, they indeed do just that: they have say 100 private servers, each one with hundreds of folders containing one website per folder. Then they have an Apache2 Server with as many VirtualHost as there are folders. Each VirtualHost has a prefixed ServerName, say client1.host.com, client2.host.com, etc. Each is configured to serve the right folder. The DNS subdomain records (ALIAS) are all pointing to the same Apache2 server which will be the one handling the real redirection.
Of course it's much more complex in reality, with redundancy etc, but you could be an hosting company yourself with subdomains pointing to one Apache2 configured with tons of VirtualHosts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you give me more info on this. Like everything i need... Right now I have a ubuntu server running apache2, mysql ... Do i need to run another server with a proxy that will do all redirection? So topology wise ... Web > Domain1/Domain2 > Proxy > WebServer1/WebServer2

Comment: You have two servers: 192.168.0.2 and 192.168.0.3. The second one, let's call him B, will not be accessible from the outside. You will use the first one, A, as a combo Server and Proxy. As a server it will serve files of the first "site" via Apache2 and as a proxy it will proxy requests of the second "site" to Server B's Apache2. Apache 2 will act both as a proxy and a file server.